# Find childs of element without sub-childs - Python - Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, browser-automation, web

I'm trying to create a bot. The functionality I need now is to find a way to get only childs of an element without sub-childs. Take this as example:

```
<Body>
   <child1>Hi</child1>
       <subChild>Woh</subChild>
   <child2>Hey</child2>
       <subChild>Weee</subChild>
</Body>
</HTML>
```

I want to find all child elements for  but when I do so by:

```
    childs = Body.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")
```

It's length by **len(childs)** is 4 instead of 2. Hope you understood.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `*` means everything, that won't work. You want to have a look at `child`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
childs = Body.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")
```

You are using xpath "//*" which means any element under the root .

To find direct child element of body use

```
childs = Body.find_elements_by_xpath("./*")
```

Here . , Means current node which is the body

And /*  means all direct childs of current node , which is body

Comment: Thanks man! Works perfectly...